# pgcrypto extension is installed but its functions are not available

Tags: postgresql

On clients server I had a problem - I did not have permissions to create extension `pgcrypto`. So server admin did it for me, and now I can see in `pg_available_extensions` that `pgcrypto` is installed (`1.1`), however its functions are not available for me:

```
=> select gen_random_uuid();
ERROR:  function gen_random_uuid() does not exist
LINE 1: select gen_random_uuid();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Also I don't have permissions to drop extension (which might be a clue what's wrong?):

```
=> drop extension pgcrypto;
ERROR:  must be owner of extension pgcrypto
```

Any idea what's wrong and why I can't see `pgcrypto` functions? Something with permissions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several possible explanations:

- PostgreSQL version is older than 9.4. This function `gen_random_uuid()` did not exist before
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4.html :

  > Add UUID random number generator gen_random_uuid() to pgcrypto (Oskari
  >   Saarenmaa)

  Use `select version();` to check the version.
- or it's 9.4+, but the extension was created in a schema that is not in the `search_path` of your SQL session. Use the meta-command `\dx` in psql to list the installed extensions, and check the `Schema` column.
- or the extension is in a schema included in `search_path`, but the db user lacks the permission to look into it. Grant it with: `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO role_name`.

Comment: Is there, perhaps, a 3rd possible explanation? I'm on pg9.6 and created extension pgcrypto in "extensions" schema which *is* in my search_path but I still get "No function matches"

Comment: @Reinsbrain: could be a permission problem. Make sure the user has been granted `USAGE` on the schema, for instance.

Comment: @DanielVérité : thanks that was it - perhaps worthy of expanding your already good answer

Comment: The third option helped me-- I had to look in the "public" schema for the method by default, as I didn't know it was created for a schema. Thanks!

Comment: There's the fourth option - PEBKAC, you forgot to specify database name, as these extensions are per DB.